# Почему не работает вывод картинок

Tags: java

Почему выдает ошибку и не признает Graphics g? Из библиотеки привязал. Все прописал вроде. Что не так ?[image: 111]

Answer (score 1):

Лишняя ';'

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // code
        }
    };
```

Должно быть:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // code
        }
    };
```